# Java 8 automatically using multicore?

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing, java-8, multicore

I did some tests a year ago concerning multicore with java 7. First I implemented some calculations only in the main thread (CPU usage showed that only one core did all the work) and then I implemented Callable with an ExecutorService instance. While running it all cores where doing the work.

Now, one year, later I have to implement a little programm (using java 8) which interpolates a lot of data. All the work is implemented in the main thread (without Callable and ExecutorService) but when I'm running the programm the CPU usage shows me, that all 4 cores are at 98%.

So does java 8 automatically distribute the work on all CPU cores? I'm confused...

Here some code...

MapGenerator.java

```
    Region[][] regions = new Region[numOfRegions][numOfRegions];

    for(int x = 0; x < regions.length; x++){
        for(int z = 0; z < regions[x].length; z++){
            newLat = SRTMHandler.getNewLatitude(startLat, z * regionSize * 16);
            newLon = SRTMHandler.getNewLongitude(startLon, x * regionSize * 16, newLat);

            regions[x][z] = new Region(x, z, regionSize, newLat, newLon);
        }
    }
```

Region.java:

```
private Chunk[] chunks;    

public Region(int x, int z, int size, float startLat, float startLon){
    this.chunks = new Chunk[this.size][this.size];
    //Init stuff
    float newLat = this.startLat, newLon = this.startLon;

    for(int newX = 0; newX < this.size; newX++){
        for(int newZ = 0; newZ < this.size; newZ++){
            newLat = SRTMHandler.getNewLatitude(this.startLat, newZ * 16);
            newLon = SRTMHandler.getNewLongitude(this.startLon, newX * 16, newLat);

            this.chunks[newX][newZ] = new Chunk(this.x * this.size + newX, this.z * this.size + newZ, 16, 900, this, newLat, newLon);
        }
    }
}
```

Chunk.java: (SRTMHandler.getHeightForLatLon() does some geo calculations and then reads a value in a byte array, nothing special)

```
public Chunk(int x, int z, int size, int height, Region r, float startLat, float startLon){
    this.blocks = new Block[size][size][height];
    //Init stuff

    try {
        this.calcSurface();
        //System.out.println("Finished " + this.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void calcSurface() throws IOException{
    int x1 = this.x;
    int x2 = this.x + 16;
    int z1 = this.z;
    int z2 = this.z + 16;
    final int radius = 45;
    float q11 = SRTMHandler.getHeightForLatLon(SRTMHandler.getNewLatitude(this.startLat, (-1)*radius), SRTMHandler.getNewLongitude(this.startLon, (-1)*radius, this.startLat));
    float q12 = SRTMHandler.getHeightForLatLon(SRTMHandler.getNewLatitude(this.startLat, radius), SRTMHandler.getNewLongitude(this.startLon, (-1)*radius, this.startLat));
    float q21 = SRTMHandler.getHeightForLatLon(SRTMHandler.getNewLatitude(this.startLat, (-1)*radius), SRTMHandler.getNewLongitude(this.startLon, radius, this.startLon));
    float q22 = SRTMHandler.getHeightForLatLon(SRTMHandler.getNewLatitude(this.startLat, radius), SRTMHandler.getNewLongitude(this.startLon, radius, this.startLat));

    for(int x = 0; x < this.blocks.length; x++){
        for(int z = 0; z < this.blocks[x].length; z++){
            float height = Interpolation.biLerp(x, z, q11, q12, q21, q22, x1, x2, z1, z2);

            this.blocks[x][z][(int)Math.round(height)] = new Block(this.x * this.size + x, this.z * this.size + z, (int)Math.round(height), BlockType.Grass, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java 8's functional programming features, specifically parallel streams?

Comment: When aparapi/parallelforall becomes fully supplied, even gpus can be used automatically using java-only codes, lambdas.

Comment: Could you provide a small code sample?

Comment: I provided the main code above ;)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Except for GPUs are not .. General enough for general code. And it's a non-trivial transformation from Java -> GPU-compatible at large. Thus such is just a pipe dream without a *specific* problem application ..

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but two hints: garbage collection may happen in parallel; to find the threads which are active within the process, try attaching jvisualvm when running.

Comment: Well this is nothing new and wont change, one thread can use maximum one cpu-thread (hald a core in hyperthreading).

Comment: How are we supposed to know what these method in `SRTMHandler` do?

Comment: Suggest you try supplying the following argument to the JVM to control the GC, watch the CPU/core usage with that active, and comment again:  -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java 8 does not automatically distribute the work on all CPU cores, unless your code requests it explicitly (for example by using parallel streams).

In some special cases the Hotspot compiler will [auto-vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization) the code, see for example [JDK-6340864](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6340864). However, automatic vectorization is using special [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) CPU instructions, not multiple CPUs.

Also see these answers:

- [Does the JVM have the ability to detect opportunities for parallelization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929184/does-the-jvm-have-the-ability-to-detect-opportunities-for-parallelization)
- [Automatic parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326666/automatic-parallelization)

(Note that I rewrote the answer, removing the part which was corrected by the comments)

Comment: Compilers do some limited auto-vectorization, which is a form of automatic parallelization.

Comment: Matlab does automatic parallelization when you operate over large matrices. It uses all cores when necessary.

Comment: I would like to find an evidence for that : "unless your code requests it explicitly (for example by using parallel streams)". How java can request explicitly some pattern of distribution of threads over cores from OS? Is that reasonable? I think only OS is in control of such matters.

Comment: @VladimirNabokov Java does not request a thread to run on a specific processor, that is indeed the job of the OS. But if you want to use all cores, you need to start enough threads manually: neither the OS nor Java will start threads automatically.

Comment: @VladimirNabokov Yeah, and I never said that this is Java's power. Please read the original question: the op experienced CPU usage in all cores although using only one thread. My answer should be interpreted in that context.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this situation too. In my case, it is the frequent garbage collection that causes a significant high (98%) CPU usage. As pointed out by several comments under the original questions, the java GC uses multi-threading by default.

In my opinion, your program is not CPU bound. Therefore, it is not likely to fully use 4 cores. On the other hand, when there is not enough heap space allocated for your program, the frequent GC will easily exhaust the CPU resource. After increasing the heap size, everything is just fine.