# Running a single threaded app across multiple cores/cpu's

Tags: multithreading, cpu

I have a single-threaded java application that I'd like to make run on multiple cores.  Is there a software that'll allow me to essentially "combine" multiple cores into one logical unit for the software to run on, with minimal to no changes to the underlying software?

If not, how would I go about addressing this issue without changing too much of the java application?

Comment: You have to rewrite the code to enable it to use multiple threads, THese things do not happen by magic

Answer (score 2):

**No**, this is basically a fundamental problem in hardware utilization. There is currently no uniform way of *automatically* parallelizing single-threaded applications (aside from running the application as multiple processes).

This is well established and has been the focus of compiler research for decades. That being said, it is probably *not* impossible, but evidently very hard to achieve.

More info:

- [Automatic parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3326666/873025)
- [Does the JVM have the ability to detect opportunities for parallelization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929184/873025)